# High-speed USB 2.0 data transfer

Tags: microcontroller, usb, serial-bus, swd

How can I send data from an MCU at rates as high as 30 Mb/s to a PC? I can't find a suitable SWD to USB 2.0 bridge IC, so I assume there must be a better way of sending a lot of data over USB.

I know that some MCU have a built-in UART, but I’m looking for something faster. How do devices such as webcams or external drives deal with high-speed data transfer?

Comment: MCUs and webcams etc don't use UART for USB. They have USB built in. Some have USB 2 with ULPI for 480Mbs. Some have built-in USB 3.

Comment: FX2/FX3 are parallel to USB ASICs. I've measured 380 MB/s through the USB 3 version. Beware that USB is complicated if you want faster than UART.

Comment: Just a note: The baud rate set for a virtual serial connection over USB is not maintained on the USB transport. If both communication partners use their USB modules directly, the effective speed is much higher. Only if a real serial line is involved, the set baud rate is relevant. I found this some years ago with an AVR90usb1287 connected via USB (1.1? I don't remember) to a PC, reaching about 1 MBit/s with a baud rate set to 2400.

Comment: Where does "SWD" come into the picture? The only SWD I'm familiar with is a debugging/programming interface and not typically used for communication.

Answer (score 6):

For 30Mb/s you need a microcontroller with a built-in USB2 high-speed peripheral.

Note USB requires the USB core which handles protocol duties, and the USB PHY which handles PHYsical things like actual signals. It's much simpler to pick a micro with integrated USB PHY.

If you mean 30Mb/s (megabits) then the micro doesn't need to be powerful, and pretty much any 32 bit micro with USB2 should be able to do it. If it's 30MB/s (megabytes) then you will need to make sure the USB core has proper DMA, preferably scatter-gather or at least a FIFO. It's important to be able to queue packets, if the hardware needs to be re-primed via an interrupt after each packet it will use much more CPU. 30 MB/s on a chip with a 50MHz clock is 6 clocks per 32-bit word, a good DMA needs one clock per 32-bit word, but you still might want to pick a chip capable of a higher clock frequency.

Of course, gathering the data to send to the PC is a matter left to you and may also require a significant amount of processing power and DMA.

Watch out, "USB2 full speed" is 12Mbps, "USB2 high speed" is 480Mbps, so just because it has a 2 doesn't mean it's the fast one!

For this data rate, USB offers you two choices: bulk mode or isochronous mode.

Isochronous is for constant data rate, real time, with guaranteed latency and throughput but no retransmission in case of error. Typical use case is audio: if you're watching a movie using a USB soundcard, you don't want the lipsync to be off so latency has to be constant and guaranteed.

Bulk is easier to use, it's basically a pipe. Proper transmission is guaranteed with retransmission in case of error, but latency and bandwidth are not guaranteed.

So for example if you're using a USB soundcard (isochronous) while copying data to a USB flash stick, isochronous packets have priority and guaranteed bandwidth, while bulk packets for your flash stick will use the rest of the bandwidth.

In your case, unless you have a very specific reason to choose isochronous and you know what you're doing... you should choose bulk, it's much simpler.

On the computer side, I recommend libusb with python. It's very simple to setup a bulk pipe, and last time I checked (about 10 years ago) it had no trouble reaching 480Mbps on USB2 bulk.

On the micro side, it depends what micro you'll use. There will be some setup. USB is both very simple and complicated. It's a bit hard to get at the beginning. It's simple because it's designed for very dumb devices that run on a 10c microcontroller like a mouse, so the host (PC) will do absolutely all the thinking. It's also complicated because even if your device is smart, it has to be dumb and do exactly what it's told.

Here's an example: when the host asks the device to transmit (because it can't transmit unless the host tells it to) the bus is held locked in transaction during the device response time, so it must be very fast. The timeout is very tiny. In fact, the USB peripheral won't have time to ask your CPU to do anything. If a packet was queued in the hardware it will be sent as a reply, otherwise you get an interrupt saying "we were asked for a packet but we had nothing to send". Even "interrupt" USB transfers work like this, which means they're actually the host polling your device 1000 times per second and asking "is there an interrupt?" which is... completely the opposite of what an interrupt is. Half the learning curve is getting into the proper USB mindset.

The simplest way for you is to search for example code of USB bulk transfer on your microcontroller of choice. Then watch out, because the hardware abstraction layers and drivers on some micros are quite terrible and while the hardware will do 480Mbps without trouble, the libraries will give you 10Mbps so you have to rewrite the whole driver to get what the hardware is capable of (ahem LPC4330). It's best to find someone who posted on a forum bragging they got the full bandwidth and look at what they're using.

Then there's Cypress FX2 USB microcontrollers, which present a 8-bit FIFO to your hardware and create a USB bulk pipe to the PC. Some chips from FTDI also do the same. It's nice if your hardware likes a 8-bit fifo interface, like a FPGA. But it's not ideal for a micro, a dedicated peripheral with DMA that can access the micro's RAM is a lot more practical.

Answer (score 3):

Many microcontrollers (for one example, the SAM3X series as found in the Arduino Due) have a built in high speed USB host capable of transmitting up to 480 Mbps.

If you need USB connectivity, select a device which provides USB connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

The TI TM4C129x USB microcontrollers have an integrated USB 2.0 controller, but the integrated PHY only supports full-speed (12Mbps) and low-speed (1.5Mbps).

To use high-speed (480Mbps) requires an external High Speed USB PHY, as shown on the [USB High Speed Reference Design for ARM® Cortex®-M4F Based High Speed TM4C129x MCU](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-TM4C129USBHS).

Not sure if need a single chip solution, or if an external PHY is acceptable.